# Fine-tuning Glove Embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

Has anyone tried to fine-tune **Glove embeddings** on a domain-specific corpus?
**Fine-tuning word2vec** embeddings has proven very efficient for me in a various NLP tasks, but I am wondering whether generating a cooccurrence matrix on my domain-specific corpus, and training glove embeddings (initialized with pre-trained embeddings) on that corpus would generate similar improvements.

Comment: why do you want to fine-tune glove specifically? have you consider methods like this one for any kind of general word embedding https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146, http://nlp.fast.ai/category/classification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself am trying to do the exact same thing. You can try [mittens](https://github.com/ashutoshsingh0223/mittens).

They have succesfully built a framework for it. Christopher D. Manning(co-author of GloVe) is associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

`word2vec` and `Glove` are a techniques for producing word embeddings, i.e., for modelling text (a set of sentences) into computer-readable vectors.

While `word2vec` trains on the local context (neighboring words), `Glove` will look for words co-occurrence in a whole text or corpus, its approach is more global.

**word2vec**

There are two main approaches for `word2vec`, in which the algorithm loops through the worlds of the sentence. For each current word `w` it will try to predict

- the neighboring words from `w` and its context, this is the `Skip-Gram` approach
- `w` from its context, this is the `CBOW` approach

Hence, `word2vec` will produce a similar embedding for words with similar contexts, for instance a noun in singular and its plural, or two synonyms.

**Glove**

The main intuition underlying the `Glove` model is the simple observation that ratios of word-word co-occurrence probabilities have the potential for encoding some form of meaning. In other words the embeddings are based on the computation of distances between pairs of target words. The model computes the distance between two target words in a text by analyzing the co-occurence of those two target words with some other probe words (contextual words).

https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

For example, consider the co-occurrence probabilities for target words "ice" and "steam" with various probe words from the vocabulary. Here are some actual probabilities from a 6 billion word corpus:[image]

As one might expect, "ice" co-occurs more frequently with "solid" than it does with "gas", whereas "steam" co-occurs more frequently with "gas" than it does with "solid". Both words co-occur with their shared property "water" frequently, and both co-occur with the unrelated word "fashion" infrequently. Only in the ratio of probabilities does noise from non-discriminative words like "water" and "fashion" cancel out, so that large values (much greater than 1) correlate well with properties specific to "ice", and small values (much less than 1) correlate well with properties specific of "steam". In this way, the ratio of probabilities encodes some crude form of meaning associated with the abstract concept of thermodynamic phase.

Also, Glove is very good at analogy, and performs well on the word2vec dataset.

Comment: Very suggestive explanation and summary in short time.

Comment: So practically in the example given, bearing in mind the word fashion, a value very close to 1 P(k|ice)/P(k|steam) would mean both words are either correlated to an extent to that word or not correlated to that word? (e.g) for Fashion we have 0.96, both Ice and Steam are not correlated with Fashion. But is the vice-versa available? I think yes, since water has a value of 1.36 (close to 1) and both solid and gas co-occur with water? Thank you for the explanations.

Comment: A value close to one means that both target words, ice and steam, have about the same co-occurrence with a probe word, say, fashion. This means that both words have equally not much to do with fashion. A ratio very different from one means that one of the two target words is very close to the probe word. I hope this will help ...

Comment: Thank you, I understood. For some reason I thought that there are 4 cases but in fact there are 3.